# Why query not returning result and how to add thousand separator in sales column

Tags: mysql

I am trying to retrieve results from this query, but it is not fetching any record:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(BILLDATE,'%M-%Y'), SUM(GROSSAMOUNT), SUM(NETAMOUNT)
FROM BILLDETAILS
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(BILLDATE,'%M-%Y') BETWEEN 'May-2011' AND 'Jul-2011'
GROUP BY MONTH(BILLDATE), YEAR(BILLDATE)
ORDER BY YEAR(BILLDATE) DESC, MONTH(BILLDATE);
```

I also want to display SUM(GrossAmount) and Sum(NetAmount) as, for example, 1,10,20,356

Comment: Why do you use date_format in that way? where month(billdate) between 5 and 7 and year(billdate) = 2011 or, even better, where billdate between '2011-05-01' and '2011-07-31'

Comment: As @nick rulez points out, your WHERE query is not right. You are performing a string comparison, not a date comparison.

Comment: This is _two_ questions. Don't write two in one, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is doing a string comparison, not a date comparison.  Try something like this instead:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(BILLDATE,'%M-%Y'), SUM(GROSSAMOUNT), SUM(NETAMOUNT)
FROM BILLDETAILS
WHERE BILLDATE BETWEEN '2011-05-01' AND '2011-07-01'
GROUP BY MONTH(BILLDATE), YEAR(BILLDATE)
ORDER BY YEAR(BILLDATE) DESC, MONTH(BILLDATE);
```

There are a variety of ways to specify the dates in the WHERE clause.  Have a look at the [Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) reference for alterntives.  Example:

```
...
WHERE BILLDATE BETWEEN '2011-05-01' AND '2011-05-01' + INTERVAL 2 MONTH
...
```

You may find the [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function useful for converting strings to dates:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('May-2011', '%M-%Y');
+----------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('May-2011', '%M-%Y') |
+----------------------------------+
| 2011-05-00                       |
+----------------------------------+
```

So your `WHERE` clause could be:

```
WHERE BILLDATE BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('May-2011', '%M-%Y')
                   AND STR_TO_DATE('Jul-2011', '%M-%Y')
```

To format the value, use the [FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function:

```
SELECT FORMAT('11020356', 0);
+-----------------------+
| FORMAT('11020356', 0) |
+-----------------------+
| 11,020,356            |
+-----------------------+
```

...although formatting is usually best left to the application.  If you format it in MySQL, processing it in the application might become a bit tricky.

Comment: What about thousand separator?

Comment: @RPK: I was just adding that... :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(BILLDATE,'%M-%Y'), SUM(GROSSAMOUNT), SUM(NETAMOUNT)
FROM BILLDETAILS
where billdate between '2011-05-01' and '2011-07-31'
GROUP BY MONTH(BILLDATE);
```

if you're looking for records within 3 months in the same year you don't need year() function.

You can also take a look at [format() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_format)

Comment: Date in Format (MMM-yyyy) is coming via C# DTPicker.

Comment: @RPK: What? Where did _that_ come from? And what is the consequence (if any) of it here?

Comment: @Tomalak: When user selects Month-Year from DTPicker, it is inserted into the query.

Comment: @RPK: So you don't even have the ability to modify this query? It's not "yours"?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you compare dates as strings in `WHERE`. If you can't use dates there (why?) you have to format the dates at least the way which works, ie in `yyyymm` format:

```
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(BILLDATE,'%Y%m') BETWEEN '201105' AND '201107'
```